# How to pass data between unnested components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a `vue` application that is made up of vue components. The basic page is `App.vue` and is something like this:

```
<template>    
 <div id="app">
      <site-header></site-header> <!-- This is a vue component -->
        <div>
          <router-link :to="{ path: '/new'}">New Post</router-link>
          <router-view></router-view> <!-- newpost.vue will be loaded here -->
        </div>
      <site-footer></site-footer> <!-- This is a vue component -->
    </div>
</template>
```

When a user clicks on the `New Post` link, a view is loaded which contains a single-file `component` that lets the user create a new post. This `component` is called `newpost.vue`.

The `site-header` component has a `div` area which needs to display errors in the application that could come from any other `component`... because the `site-header` is present on all pages:

*siteheader.vue*

```
<template>
  <header>
   <div id="global-error">
   <p> {{globalErrorMessage}} </p> <!-- Need to display error messages here -->
   </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

So my question is:

1. In order to get `{{globalErrorMessage}}` to work, do I need to create a `prop` in *siteheader.vue* for this data?
2. If I need to create a `prop`, how do I pass data from any `<router-view>` loaded component to the *siteheader.vue* prop?
3. The above seems impossible because *newpost.vue* will never have a parent/child relationship with *siteheader.vue*. They are siblings on the same level so how does one component listen to another component's emit event?
4. Given that, do I create `data(){ return {globalErrorMessage: "" } }` in *siteheader.vue* and then have a `computed` method that can change this data? If so, how does *newpost.vue* access the method in *siteheader.vue* to change the data field for the error message?
5. Finally, is all the above total nonsense and is `Vuex` state management the way to go? This also doesn't seem right because each error is unique to that visitor. State doesn't have to be maintained for errors.

I have no idea how to approach this hence the above questions.

Comment: Yes, you should use vuex for this, central source of truth. Or use vue-portal if you want to avoid vuex. Generally having vuex does not hurt and as project grows you see its beneift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `Vuex` is the elegant option especially if the application becomes more complex, you can use an `event-bus` to send messages from the first component to the second:

**event-bus.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

**newpost.vue:**

```
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';
...
EventBus.$emit('set-global-error-message', 'Something went wrong');
```

**siteheader.vue:**

```
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';
...
created() {
  EventBus.$on("set-global-error-message", this.setGlobalErrorMessage);
},
methods: {
  setGlobalErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
    this.globalErrorMessage = errorMessage;
  },
},
```

Comment: If each error is unique to that visitor, how does Vuex ensure that other users dont see the same error as someone else?

Comment: @volumeone ``vuex`` is a client-side store bound to the web app, so it stores only the data of each instance/user

Comment: Looks like I need to read up on vuex because I thought it was application-wide state management so if someone clicks on a "Like", everyone's component would update to show that "Like"

Comment: @volumeone no it's not a common database, it's used as a global data source for the SPA. Here is somewhere you can start: https://vuex.vuejs.org

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, if you want your component not depend on a global state and just show the message that it was provided. If you are fine with it being a component that accesses global state like from vuex, then no need for prop. You can even register custom module in vuex just for this component.
2. There is no way to pass data upwards from children to parent directly, either you need to update a central state where child updates the data and parent displays data, or you need to emit events from children where parent listens and updates its sibling or via custom event bus.
3. You can do this through their parent, App.vue will need to manage that data flow.
4. Changing local state of a component outside of it is not good even though you can hack around. You should pass the data as prop rather.
5. Vuex lives only in the memory e.g it's per browser tab unless you selected localStorage as the persistent storage, even then that's per visitor. Meaning, people won't share the vuex state of each other's browser.

These are just off the top of my head.